# What is the meaning of these restriction notices

Tags: here-api

A number of categories contain one or more of the following notations:

> - Note: This category is a HERE protected category.
> - Note: This category is a HERE owned category.
> - Note: This category is a HERE search-only category.
>
> (RESTRICTED)

For example, airports is such a listed category.  Do these restrictions mean I may not search for the location of airport?

Comment: What HERE API do you use?

Comment: places api.  there is a list of categories and their sub-categories.  [link]https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/place_categories/places-category-system.html.  you'll see the restricted categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may search for RESTRICTED categories and still find results. RESTRICTED doesn't mean you cannot search for it. It means that these data should be from highest places quality providers (for example: government or HERE driven quality).

Example: In the query below I am able to search for Airport terminal category  (RESTRICTED) and get relevant results. Hope you find this useful.

```
https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/explore?at=50.038174%2C8.562152&cat=400-4000-4582&cs=pds&Accept-Language=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.5&app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxx
```